# How to join an ActiveRecord result with select_all result by a column ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

```
class Author
  has_many :post
end

class Post
  belong_to :author
  has_many :content
end

class Content
  belong_to :post 
  (column: section)
end



c = Content.select("post_id").where("section like ?", 'foo%')
p =  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all(Post.select("title, post_id ").joins(:author).where(:id => c.map(&:post_id)).to_sql)
```

how to join `c` and `p` to become a table-like structure by `post_id` column ?

just like in SQL:

```
  select * from c,p where c.post_id = q.post_id ;
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
@posts = Content.find(:all, :include => :post)
```

will generate SQL as you wish. You can access separately content for each post in `each` cycle or generate plane table like DB returns performing something like this:

```
@posts = Content.find(:all, :include => :post).map{|c| c.merge(c.post)}
```

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `merge' for #<School: ... >   ,  any idea?  thanks.

Comment: oh, sorry, my mistake. This won't work, because it's not a Hash, it's object. You can play around and replace for example `c.merge(c.post)` with `{:post_id => c.post.id, :content_name => c.name, :post_name => c.post.name}` or whatever you like. More important here is that Rails already has all necessary data from DB and you can use them as you like.

Comment: sorry, I'm just not familiar with it.  I replaced ` c.merge(c.post)` with `{:post_id => c.post.id}`. But `:post_id` is undefined.  Still trying to figure it out...